# Objects as pointers in javascripts

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to use something like pointers in javascripts, this is what I have,

I have a set of values: `{chart2:6, chart3:4, chart5:7}`. For example I want to write a function where I can pass to it `chart2` and it will return to me the value `6`.

Thank you for your help.

this is the code im using now:

```
function pointers(copy,paste) {

            obj[copy].value = paste;

}


function getPointer(copy) {
            return obj[copy].value;

}

pointers(selectedIdsArray[s],semiId);

alert(selectedIdsArray[s]);
```

im calling the pointers function inside a loop and alerting them too in  aloop,
but it giving the following error:

```
ReferenceError: obj is not defined
```

Comment: That's sorta what an object does, it holds keys and values, and you can use the key to get the value, you don't need a function, and you certainly don't need pointers.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried so far? What do you want to it to look like.

Comment: You can also use points. obj.chart2

Comment: I have added the code im using

Comment: Where are `selectedIdsArray`, `s`, `semiId` defined? Where did you think was `obj` defined (it obviously is not)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no C-style pointers in javascript. Your getPointer function needs to see the obj variable to be able to access it (like in the snippet below).

```
var obj = {
    foo: { value: "foo" },
    bar: { value: "bar" }
};

function pointers(copy, paste) {
    obj[copy].value = paste;
}


function getPointer(copy) {
    return obj[copy].value;
}
```